# Why does the code get compiled when I use !!= C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand how does the code get compiled when I use (!!=)
Apparently the 2 snippets below do the same thing.
Why are both permissable?

```
if (4 !!= 5)
  Console.WriteLine("vvvvvv");
```

the above does the same thing as:

```
if (4 != 5)
   Console.WriteLine("vvvvvv");
```

Comment: Use Visual Studio to reformat it and see what you get. The compiler sees it as `if (4! != 5)` .

Comment: One of the `!` is redundant.

Comment: @Liad: No, both of them do something.  See below.

Comment: To be redundant, the "`!`" in "`!=`" would have to have an effect separate from the "`=`" so that the second could have no stacking effect (redundancy). That is not the case. `!=` is a separate operator, and not `!` to negate `=` (How would you negate assignment? "You are *not* to be assigned this value." ??).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression `4 !!= 5` is parsed as the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) applied to  4, and then `!=` applied to that expression and 5. That is, `(4!) != 5`.

According to the [draft spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/nullable-reference-types-specification#the-null-forgiving-operator), a null forgiving expression is a kind of primary expression:

```
primary_expression
    : ...
    | null_forgiving_expression
    ;

null_forgiving_expression
    : primary_expression '!'
    ;
```

and that:

> The postfix `!` operator has no runtime effect - it evaluates to the result of the underlying expression. Its only role is to change the null state of the expression to "not null", and to limit warnings given on its use.

In other words, the `!` after 4 does nothing and is very redundant. The constant 4 is never null after all :)

Comment: To clarify, *the ! after 4 does nothing and is very redundant* means that there is no point in checking null for constant values. Two exclamations `!!=` in a row is not necessarily redundant depending on the context. Adding the clarification due to other comments on the question regarding redundancy.

Answer (score 7):

This only works in C# 8.0 and later. See [null-forgiving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving).

I believe you are just stating that 4 could be null and telling the compiler that it should not show errors if 4 does happen to be null.

Comment: Sort of. You're stating that the compiler should not bother to check whether or not `4` might be null.

Comment: Ah, so this is one of those weird "I put my spaces in the wrong places" things.

Comment: Yes, it could be written as `(4!!=5)`, `(4! != 5)`, `( 4 ! != 5)`, `( 4 ! != 5 )`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To complement other answers - in case you don't understand something about what is happening in terms of compilation you can use tools such decompilers - for example an online one - https://sharplab.io/. Among the others capabilities it provides ability to see the decompiled to [IL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)(not very useful here), C# (basically desugared version of the code, for this one - [see](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlgHYAuA/IuQJSba5vkBmiFiAhLwF5EAVkas2E5BACcpAEQA3JcrmMA3OMQBfWFqA===), also not very useful here) and also syntax tree (for this one - [see](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzsA+ACBMBGAsAKFgZgAQKwYSwG80tSdtYAWLAWQAoBLAO2AH4sGBKIksvhgGZZGWAISiAvFgCsnXnwU5EATjoAiAG5btazgG55WAL5ojQA)), which can be useful in this particular case. I've used next code (so it can be compiled in release mode without optimizing constants out):

```cs
public class C {
    public void M(int? i) {
        if (i !!= 5)
            Console.WriteLine("vvvvvv");
    }
}
```

If you expand CompilationUnit ->
ClassDeclaration -> MethodDeclaration -> Body ->
IfStatement -> Condition -> Left you will see that it is actually `SuppressNullableWarningExpression` with operand being `i`:

[image]

[image]

With sharplab.io kindly highlighting the part of the code which is represented by selected syntax node. So as others described you can see that compiler parses your code as `4` followed by null-forgiving operator.